# Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I have reqest with block. But the compiler issues a warning

> "Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain
>   cycle"

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[generalInstaImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"success");
    [generalInstaImage setImage: image];
    [weakSelf saveImage:generalInstaImage.image withName:data[@"id"]];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fail");
}];
```

I try example write like `weakSelf.generalInstaImage`, but then the compiler generates an error and do not compile.

Comment: what is the error? try using `id` or the actual class name instead of `typeof(self)`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Consider this warning:

> Capturing `self` strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain
>   cycle

When you receive the above warning, you should review your block for:

- any explicit references to `self`; or
- any implicit references to `self` caused by referencing any instance variables.

Let's imagine that we have some simple class property that was a block (this will experience the same "retain cycle" warnings as your question, but will keep my examples a little simpler):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^block)(void);
```

And let's assume we had some other class property we wanted to use inside our block:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someString;
```

If you reference `self` within the block (in my example below, in process of accessing this property), you will obviously receive that warning about the retain cycle risk:

```
self.block = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.someString);
};
```

That is remedied via the pattern you suggested, namely:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.block = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf.someString);
};
```

Less obvious, you will also receive the "retain cycle" warning if you reference an instance variable of the class inside the block, for example:

```
self.block = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", _someString);
};
```

This is because the `_someString` instance variable carries an implicit reference to `self`, and is actually equivalent to:

```
self.block = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", self->_someString);
};
```

You might be inclined to try to adopt weak self pattern here, too, but you can't. If you attempt the `weakSelf->_someString` syntax pattern, the compiler will warn you about this:

> Dereferencing a `__weak` pointer is not allowed due to possible null value caused by race condition, assign it to `strong` variable first

You therefore resolve this by using the `weakSelf` pattern, but also create a local `strong` variable within the block and use that to dereference the instance variable:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.block = ^{
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        NSLog(@"%@", strongSelf->_someString);

        // or better, just use the property
        //
        // NSLog(@"%@", strongSelf.someString);
    }
};
```

As an aside, this creation of a local `strong` reference, `strongSelf`, inside the block has other advantages, too, namely that if the completion block is running asynchronously on a different thread, you don't have to worry about `self` being deallocated while the block is executing, resulting in unintended consequences.

This `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern is very useful when dealing with block properties and you want to prevent retain cycles (aka strong reference cycles), but at the same time ensuring that `self` cannot be deallocated in the middle of the execution of the completion block.

FYI, Apple discusses this pattern in the "non-trivial cycles" discussion further down in the [Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4) section of the *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes.*

---

You report that you received some "error" when you referenced `weakSelf.generalInstaImage` in your example. This is the correct way to resolve this "retain cycle" warning, so if you received some warning, you should share that with us, as well as show us how you declared the property.

Comment: Very complete answer! +1

Comment: "will generate an exception" No, it will not generate an exception. It will lead to undefined behavior (likely a segmentation fault).

Comment: @newacct My main point was to dispel the notion of trying to dereference ivars with weak pointers, but I appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Good explanation about memory management and blocks, however in the question isn't clear that the block is a property of `generalInstaImage`. Sometimes XCode isn't smart enough to detect these cases, and this is one of them, because `setImageWithURLRequest:requestWithURL:placeholderImage:success:` is a method from `SDWebImage` and it doesn't seem to declare any block property.

Comment: Pablo, yep, the compiler doesn't know whether the other class correctly avoids the strong reference cycle. It only knows that passing `self` could possibly result in such a cycle. (Perhaps their use of "likely" goes too far.) That having been said, we often program defensively, assuming that any asynchronous method _might_ keep a reference to the block. Ideally, we want our classes as loosely coupled as possible, we shouldn't make too many assumptions about how the other class behaves. IMHO, you should use `weakSelf` pattern, regardless, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Use `__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self`

Comment: This may eliminate the compiler warning, but can have disastrous results if `self` was deallocated by the time the block is called, as you'll have a dangling pointer to a deallocated object. This is, at the risk of stating the obvious, very _unsafe._