# add SKAction to Sprite queue run one after another

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I listen to touch and add SKAction to a sprite. If existing actions are not complete yet, I want the action to be added to a queue so it will execute one after another.
Any experienced similar design?

I did using Array and Block. If there is any easier approach?

```
@interface GAPMyScene()
@property(strong,nonatomic)SKSpriteNode*ufo;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray*animationQueue;
@property(copy,nonatomic)void(^completeMove)();
@end

@implementation GAPMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.ufo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        self.animationQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        self.completeMove = ^(void){
            [weakSelf.ufo runAction:[SKAction sequence:[weakSelf.animationQueue copy]] completion:weakSelf.completeMove];
            NSLog(@"removeing %@", weakSelf.animationQueue);
            [weakSelf.animationQueue removeAllObjects];
        };
        [self addChild:self.ufo];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKAction*moveAnimation = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:2];
        if (![self.ufo hasActions]) {
            [self.ufo runAction:moveAnimation completion:self.completeMove];

        } else {
            [self.animationQueue addObject:moveAnimation];
            NSLog(@"in queue %@", self.animationQueue);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Just our of curiosity: Xcode shows me an ARC Retain Cycle warning for `__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`. Is that code correct?

Comment: i think so. to prevent retain cycle in block i have to make it weak reference.

Comment: Okay, the warning disappeared after I used the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17011096/867635). Regarding you question: I haven't found an easier approach for an animation-queue yet.

Comment: ok, the warning fixed. i have to put the weak self declaration outside of the block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can make `SKActions` run concurrently using the `group` method, and have them run sequentially using the `sequence` method.

But if you need a queuing system, rather than building your own, use the native operation queue to do this for you. So you can create a serial operation queue and add operations to it. The issue is that you don't want an operation to complete until the `SKAction` does.

So, you can wrap your `SKAction` in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass that only completes when the `SKAction` does. Then you can add your operations to a serial `NSOperationQueue`, and then it will won't start the next one until it finishes the prior one.

So, first, create an `ActionOperation` (subclassed from `NSOperation`) that looks like:

```
// ActionOperation.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class SKNode;
@class SKAction;

@interface ActionOperation : NSOperation

- (instancetype)initWithNode:(SKNode *)node action:(SKAction *)action;

@end
```

and

```
// ActionOperation.m

#import "ActionOperation.h"
@import SpriteKit;

@interface ActionOperation ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isFinished)  BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKNode *node;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKAction *action;

@end

@implementation ActionOperation

@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;

- (instancetype)initWithNode:(SKNode *)node action:(SKAction *)action
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _node = node;
        _action = action;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self.node runAction:self.action completion:^{
            self.executing = NO;
            self.finished = YES;
        }];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation methods

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

@end
```

You could then, for example, create a serial queue during the initialization process:

```
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

You can then add the operations to it:

```
SKAction *move1 = [SKAction moveTo:point1 duration:2.0];
[self.queue addOperation:[[ActionOperation alloc] initWithNode:nodeToMove action:move1]];
```

and you can later add more actions:

```
SKAction *move2 = [SKAction moveTo:point2 duration:2.0];
[self.queue addOperation:[[ActionOperation alloc] initWithNode:nodeToMove action:move2]];
```

And because the queue is serial, you know that `move2` will not be started until `move1` is done.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answer, but parameter to send to SKAction and the Node will need to be decided on runtime. E.g. I will only know which node to run on the SKAction after the end of the first SKAction

Comment: @ElliotYap That's fine. You haven't shown us how it knows which node you want perform that action on (so it's hard for me to show you the change necessary in the operation object to make that happen), but you can incorporate whatever logic you're alluding to in this `ActionOperation` (e.g. or use block/delegate pattern so caller can specify how to determine this). My point was simply that you shouldn't recreate queue mechanism when one already exists.

Comment: Understand, I'm reading on NSOperation now, Thanks for leading me to the right direction :)

Comment: [Rob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob), I found a limitation on the [Swift implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28373490/540780) of this solution when `SKactions` transmitted during initialization contains `runAction:onChildWithName:`. In this case the duration for this `SKAction` is instantaneous.