# runAction on SKNode does not complete

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsoperation, skaction

I use a subclass NSOperation to obtain serial execution of `SKAction` as described in this question: [How to subclass NSOperation in Swift to queue SKAction objects for serial execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28373490/540780)

I then modified the previous subclass in order to group animations for several nodes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600718/540780

At last, as I needed to run completion block after `SKAction` completed, I slightly modified the code by using an array of struct instead an array of tuples.

```
struct ActionData {
    let node:SKNode
    let action:SKAction
    let completion: () -> ()

    init (node:SKNode, action:SKAction, completion:() -> () = {}) {
        self.node = node
        self.action = action
        self.completion = completion
    }
}

class ActionOperation : NSOperation
{

    let _theActions:[ActionData]

    var _finished = false // Our read-write mirror of the super's read-only finished property
    var _executing = false // Our read-write mirror of the super's read-only executing property

    var _numberOfOperationsFinished = 0 // The number of finished operations


    /// Override read-only superclass property as read-write.
    override var executing:Bool {
        get { return _executing }
        set {
            willChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
            _executing = newValue
            didChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
        }
    }

    /// Override read-only superclass property as read-write.
    override var finished:Bool {
        get { return _finished }
        set {
            willChangeValueForKey("isFinished")
            _finished = newValue
            didChangeValueForKey("isFinished")
        }
    }


    // Initialisation with one action for one node
    //
    // For backwards compatibility
    //
    init(node:SKNode, action:SKAction) {
        let donnees = ActionData(node: node, action: action, completion: {})
        _theActions = [donnees]

        super.init()
    }

    init (lesActions:[ActionData]) {
        _theActions = lesActions

        super.init()
    }

    func checkCompletion() {
        _numberOfOperationsFinished++

        logGeneral.debug(">> Block completed: \(self._numberOfOperationsFinished)/\(self._theActions.count) " + self.name!)

        if _numberOfOperationsFinished ==  _theActions.count {
            self.executing = false
            self.finished = true
            logGeneral.debug("Operation Completed: " + self.name!)
        }

    }

    override func start()
    {
        if cancelled {
            finished = true
            return
        }

        executing = true

        if name == nil {
            name = "unknown"
        }


        _numberOfOperationsFinished = 0
        var operation = NSBlockOperation()

        var compteur = 0
        for actionData in _theActions {
            compteur++

            var actionName = "???"
            if let name = actionData.node.name {
                actionName = name
            }

            logGeneral.debug("operation : \(compteur)/\(self._theActions.count) " + self.name! + " " + actionName)
            operation.addExecutionBlock({
                actionData.node.runAction(actionData.action,completion:{
                    actionData.completion()
                    self.checkCompletion() })
            })
        }

        logGeneral.debug("Execute: " + self.name!)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperation(operation)

    }
}
```

The main idea is to elaborate animations by adding data of `ActionData` type, append them to an array and transmit this array to the `ActionAnimation` object.

In some random cases, some `runAction` doesn complete: they start but some of them randomly do not complete. Here is a typical log where 6 block started but only 5 completed:

```
start(): operation : 1/6 ???
start(): operation : 2/6 suppressionPion1
start(): operation : 3/6 suppressionPion2
start(): operation : 4/6 suppressionPion3
start(): operation : 5/6 suppressionPion4
start(): operation : 6/6 suppressionGroupe1
start(): Execute: animerSupprimer
checkCompletion(): >> Block completed: 1/6
checkCompletion(): >> Block completed: 2/6
checkCompletion(): >> Block completed: 3/6
checkCompletion(): >> Block completed: 4/6
checkCompletion(): >> Block completed: 5/6
```

In this case only one `runAction` failed to completed, in other case 2, 3 or none.

I really don't understand where the problem come from.

### UPDATE

In some cases the app crashed with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on main thread.  This seems to be related to `SKCSprite::update(double)`:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you are going through all this work with NSOperations just to get animation sequences. Have you looked at `SKAction.sequence` and `SKAction.group`? You can have actions run in a `sequence`, or `group` actions together, or even include groups in your sequence. You could even put a completion at the end of your sequence using `SKAction.runBlock`. They are all described in the [SKAction docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKAction).

Comment: I need to use `NSOperations` to sequence execution of animations and computations on different nodes. Maybe there is a far easy way to achieve this and I don't see it. But this is not the purpose of this question.

Comment: To @user2194039's question, you cannot add to an `SKAction` sequence after it has begun running. The approach referenced in this question ([How to subclass...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28373490/540780)) makes that possible.