# Can Clang Static Analyzer be used with Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, clang-static-analyzer

When I analyse a Swift project on Xcode 6, the build succeed with no issues. So I wonder if the Clang Static Analyser work with Swift!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, the static analyser is of no use at all with Swift.

Comment: That is why I removed all mention of the Analyser from the latest edition of my books...

Comment: I fervently hope that Apple is going to add support for the static analyzer for Swift in a future update of Xcode.

Comment: @matt, this is annoying as I wanted to use it to find an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash. Have you some tips for such problems?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Please _ask_ that question (as a question), giving details about the crash, where it occurs, what messages you get, etc., and let's discuss how to track it down.

Comment: Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683897/runaction-on-sknode-does-not-complete#comment49441652_30683897

Comment: Would a static analyzer for Swift really be that useful? It seems like the language was designed to prevent a lot of the problems that a static analyzer would catch.

Comment: @Ferruccio I agree, though, it's not the design of the language, I think, so much as the design of the compiler. Apple is willing to let compilation take longer and have the compiler be "smarter", exploring the _logic_ of your program in ways that were previously the province of the analyser.

Comment: I agree with @Ferruccio; all the logic errors the analyzer used to point seem to be either A) already included in the repertory of compiler warnings, or B) Outright Swift compiler errors. Unless I'm missing something...