# Swift <uninitialized> let property

Tags: swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, nsoperationqueue

I need some debugging help, because an error I run into is really hard.

This is a game with complex animations. However the question isn't about `SpriteKit`. I want animations to follow each other in strict order, so I implemented a subclass of `Operation`:

```
class ActionOperation: Operation
{
    var debugLabel: String?

    private(set) var actionNodes: Set<ActionNode>

    //... Other vars, isFinished etc.

    init(node: SKNode, action: SKAction) {
       actionNodes = [ActionNode(node: node, action: action)]
       super.init()
    }

    init(nodesAndActions: [(SKNode?, SKAction)]) {
        actionNodes = Set(nodesAndActions.map( {(tuple) in return 
            ActionNode(node: tuple.0, action: tuple.1)
        }))
        super.init()
    }

    override func start() { /* ... */ }
}
```

For this class details you can see [the source question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28373490/3050403). 
A helper struct:

```
extension ActionOperation {
    struct ActionNode: Hashable {
        static func ==(lhs: ActionOperation.ActionNode, rhs: ActionOperation.ActionNode) -> Bool {
            return lhs.node == rhs.node && lhs.action == rhs.action
        }

        weak var node: SKNode?

        // This constant is causing problems!
        let action: SKAction

        let setIdForHash: Int

        var hashValue: Int { return setIdForHash ^ action.hashValue }
    }
}
```

### The Problem

The instances of the `ActionOperation` are added to the `animationQueue`. Queue setup:

```
fileprivate let animationQueue = OperationQueue()

// Setup:
animationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
animationQueue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
```

Operation setup:

```
let duration = 0.35
var groupActions = [SKAction]()
for n in 0..<from.count {
    let fromIndex = from[n]
    let toIndex = to[n]
    let move = SKAction.move(to: fieldPosition(at: toIndex), duration: duration)
    let seq = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run(move, onChildWithName: "\(fromIndex)"),
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration),
        SKAction.run({
            self.piece(at: fromIndex)?.name = "\(toIndex)"
        })
    ])
    groupActions.append(seq)
}
let gravOperation = ActionOperation(node: piecesLayer, action: SKAction.group(groupActions))
gravOperation.debugLabel = "gravity"
animationQueue.addOperation(gravOperation)
```

Sometimes this queue get stack, that means one operation is executing forever. I'm trying to debug it using Xcode command line and type this:

```
p (animationQueue.operations[0] as! ActionOperation).actionNodes.first!.action
```

> `(SKAction) $R6 = <uninitialized>`

**What does it mean?** How a `let` constant in a struct can be `uninitialized`?

If I print `node`, everything is ok:

```
po (animationQueue.operations[0] as! ActionOperation).actionNodes.first!.node
```

> `<SKNode> name:'(null)' position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{178.13499450683594, -26.469999313354492}, {908.33502197265625, 1012.9400024414062}}`

Comment: Where is the initialiser of ActionOperation called? I would guess that actionNodes is nil.

Comment: @colmlg, `actionNodes` isn't Optional. How can it be `nil`? The problem is more interesting and deep.

Comment: In the case where you get bad access, what does `po (animationQueue.operations[0] as! ActionOperation).actionNodes` show you?

Comment: @PhillipMills, the same EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Interesting.  How about `po animationQueue.operations[0]` or `po animationQueue`?  (Trying to isolate exactly what is triggering the "address=0x0" part of the error message.)

Comment: @PhillipMills, it's ok.

Comment: And `animationQueue.operations[0]` says it's really an `ActionOperation` type of object?  (If so, I'm baffled.)

Comment: Yes, it prints something like `<IOSTest.ActionOperation 0x1c429fbd0 isFinished=NO isReady=YES isCancelled=NO isExecuting=YES>`. I'm also more than puzzled by this bug.

Comment: `node?.hashValue ?? 0)` strikes me as potentially very dangerous. When a node is deallocated, the hash value of the object changes. The hash value of an object should never change, otherwise you can have really serious problems.

Comment: Yes, I also don't like it, I will create additional id for hashing purposes and post my results here. *Possible* that it can affect `Set` memory management.

Comment: I updated the question. Now `hashValue` of `ActionNode` is more safe. All problems is still here. It's interesting that `po (animationQueue.operations[0] as! ActionOperation).actionNodes.count` outputs "1". (While `actionNodes` leads to bad access).

Comment: try to use `p` instead of `po` for debugging structs

Comment: @Sulthan, see the update.

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. I will post the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was caused by the way I crate group action:

```
let gravOperation = ActionOperation(node: piecesLayer, action: SKAction.group(groupActions))
```

When `groupActions` array is empty action will never be executed on the node and if we call:

```
node.run(badGroupAction, completion: { /* never called */ })
```

the `completion` will be never called. That's why queue was stuck. I think it's a `SpriteKit` flaw. I would prefer `completion` to be called immediately if we try to run empty group or sequence.

Why does `action` become `uninitialized`? I don't know, I think it's a bug, probably related to the empty array.

Comment: I reported a bug to Apple.